# How do I fix 'undefined' errors when using TypeScript Interfaces?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

TypeScript is telling me:

```
Type '{ banner: { id: number; bannerImageUrl: string; } | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Banner'.
  Property 'banner' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Banner'.ts(2322)
```

I am using Next.js, here are the files used:

**index.tsx**

```
import data from '../../json/data.json'
import Banner from '../components/home/banner'

export default function Home() {
  const home = data?.data[0].pageContent[0].home[0]
  const banner = home?.banner
  
  return (
    <Banner banner={banner}/>
  )
}
```

**banner.tsx (../components/home/banner)**

```
import Image from 'next/image'

interface Banner {
  banner: {
    id: number,
    imageUrl: string
  }
}

export default function Banner({ banner } : Banner) {
  return (
    <Image 
      className="hero__banner-image"
      src={banner.imageUrl}
      alt="Banner Image"
      fill
    />
  )
}
```

Now, the page does work properly (everything loads with no error), but I keep getting the error above in my `index.tsx` file. I have tried adding the `| undefined` such as:

```
interface {
  banner: {
    id: number,
    imageUrl: string
  } | undefined
}
```

The error is fixed, but then the src section of the image tells me that it cannot have "undefined" which makes sense since I added that the interface can be 'undefined'.

The JSON for `data?.data[0].pageContent[0].home[0]` is:

```json
{
  "home": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "banner": {
        "id": 0,
        "imageUrl": "/../public/images/bannerImage.jpg"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const banner = home?.banner` results in `banner` being of type `Banner |undefined` because of how [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) works. And the `Banner` component needs a well-defined `banner` parameter. In `Home`, you could render it conditionally:

```
banner && <Banner banner={banner}/>
```

Which makes total sense, because a `Banner` with an undefined `banner`, would render what?